# Related models in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I've started my first project in CI and got myself into a knot again!

I've created a model, controller, view and database table for "company"

A company consists of the following:

```
Company ID
Company Name
Company Registration Number
Credit Limit
Website
Address
Postcode
Country
```

My controller allows you to view a list of companies, edit a company or create a new company.

Now I want each company to have a list of "contacts".  There would be one or more contact per company.  My contacts table is like this:

```
Contact ID
Company ID (this is the foreign key)
First Name
Last Name
Position
Email Address
Telephone
Mobile
```

This is where I've gotten confused and have numerous questions as follows:

1) Should I have a completely separate model, controller and view for "contacts"?  I'm unclear whether they should be separate or whether they should be part of the "company" controller and model, since they are related.

2) My inclination is that the contacts should be a separate model.  If this is the case, when you delete a company you would want to also delete all related contacts for that company.  Should you take care of the entire deletion process in:

```
$this->company_model->delete_company($company_id) /* Delete from both company & contacts */
```

Or should you call both models like this:

```
$this->company_model->delete_company($company_id);
$this->contacts_model->delete_contacts_list($company_id);
```

3) What would/should my routing look like.  Viewing, adding and deleting contacts would only take place via a company view.  So if we view the company with ID 123 like this:

```
/company/view/123
```

How would we view the related contacts for company 123?  Like this:

```
/company/view/123/contacts
```

Or like this:

```
/contacts/123
```

I hope these questions are clear enough and thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

You just call the controller function name you just have written like this `yourcontrollermethodname/123`

then in controller call your both model

```
yourcontrollermethodname( $company_id = NULL ) {
  $this->company_model->delete_company($company_id);
  $this->company_model->delete_contacts_list($company_id);  
}
```

and in model make 2 methods delete_company and delete_contacts_list and just pass the id and delete them and if you want to call the view then in controller

```
yourcontrollermethodcallscompanylist ()
{
   // make model
   $data['company_list'] = $this->company_model->company_list();
   $this->load->view('abc',$data);
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't "contacts" be a separate model from "company", because although they're related a contact is not a company.

It would be like having an online shop and having only one model called "shop" instead of separate models for products, sales, customers, etc.

Comment: make only one model if it is shop model just put both the company and contact method there and when you are calling the method you should written like that $this->shop_model->delete_company($company_id);
    $this->shop_model->delete_contacts_list($company_id);

Comment: But what about when companies have not just contacts but also sales orders and invoices?  Surely everything shouldn't go into one model?  Isn't a model for each database table a better setup?

Comment: if you want to make separate model then you have to make different controller different model different view for each company and contacts it is hmvc pattern